# Iif condition for grouping column

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Can anyone please help me to fix the expression below?

If anyone between age of 2-15 should written next to it 51,84$

```
    =IIf((Fields!Age.Value>=2,"51,84 $",Fields!Age.Value<15,"51,84 $")
```

Comment: Name the error you encountered instead of just telling that it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `AND` operator between the two expressions.

```
=IIF(Fields!Age.Value >=2 AND Fields!Age.Value <15, "51,84 $", "Other Value")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have one more question.
How can I find total of below field. I want to have "Grand Total" in separate column.

Comment: iif(Fields!Age.Value>=0,"108","")+ IIf(Fields!Age.Value>=15,"75,60"," ")+ IIF(Fields!Age.Value >=2 AND Fields!Age.Value <15, "51,84", " ")= Grand Total

Comment: You have three intervals, so the best way to do it is to use a Switch statement: `Switch(Fields!Age.Value >= 15, 75.60, Fields!Age.Value >= 2, 51.84, Fields!Age.Value >= 0, 108, 0)`. The switch expression evaluates the first condition and if it's true returns the value after it, otherwise moves to the next condition. The final value is the value if none of the conditions is satisfied.

Comment: Also depending on what you want to do, you might have to use it with a SUM statement: SUM(Switch(....))

Comment: I really did not understand

Comment: =switch(Sum(Fields!Age.Value>=15,"75,60" ,"") + sum(Fields!Age.Value >=2 AND Fields!Age.Value <15, "51,84", " ") +sum( Fields!Age.Value>=0,"108",""))

Comment: `=SUM(Switch(Fields!Age.Value >= 15, 75.60, Fields!Age.Value >= 2, 51.84, Fields!Age.Value >= 0, 108, 0))`